# Does second optional chaining negatively impact performance

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am wondering if the presence of the second optional chaining has any negative impact whatsoever:

```
let flag = somePotentialNullObj?.someNumProp > 0 &&  somePotentialNullObj?.someOtherProp;
```

The second optional chaining is not needed, this works exactly the same:

```
let flag = somePotentialNullObj?.someNumProp > 0 && somePotentialNullObj.someOtherProp;
```

If it gets afters the &&, somePotentialNullObj can't be null or undefined, we shouldn't have to check again with `?`, right?

Comment: As usual with performance, the way to find out is to test the specific code in the specific circumstances that you find it in. We can say that the second optional chain is unnecessary, but the performance question you're asking is unlikely to bear much fruit.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the OP that optional chaining is needed in the right half of the expression.

If `someProp` is missing, the first `?.` skips the comparison and evaluates to undefined. That short-circuits the `&&`. If we get to the second half of the `&&` expression, we must've found `someProp`.

I don't know how the interpreter optimizes either OP proposal. On the surface, the second proposal would do less computation on average.